# HTML - Drop down menu closes when trying to select a nested select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, html-select

**Incorrectly marked as duplicate**

**JS Fiddle (Problem)**

[http://jsfiddle.net/xrd2b42L/12/](http://jsfiddle.net/xrd2b42L/8/)

**JS Fiddle (With Solution)**

http://jsfiddle.net/xrd2b42L/21/

**Problem**

I have a drop down menu powered by JQuery. If I put a select tag within the menu, and try to select an option, the menu automatically closes without me being able to choose an option.

This bug is not cross browser consistent. This menu works correctly in Firefox 37.01, Safari 5.1.7 and also worked in Chrome 39.

I've tried changing the JavaScript event powering the menu to a click event, but the bug still occurs.

The bug occurs in IE11 and Chrome 41.0.2272.118.

An help would be appreciated.

**Update**

I've updated the fiddle to use a mouseenter event. The issue still occurs. Kano has pointed out the issue seems to be the mouse leave event being triggered when I hover over an option within the select.

**Fix**

After 4 long hours I've managed to resolve the issue. It turns out that the mouse leave event is triggered on the select element even though the select element is a child of the element that the handlers attached to. I've fixed the javascript below so that the code now functions correctly in case anyone else experiences the issue.

**HTML**

```
<html>
<header>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</header>
<body>
<ul class = 'contentMenu jsGeneralNavigation'>
<li>Menu Item 1</li>
<li>Drop Down Menu 1
<ul>
<li>No Select</li>
<li>
<select>
<option value ='Option 1'>Option 1</option>
<option value ='Option 2'>Option 2</option>
<option value ='Option 3'>Option 3</option>    
</select>
<li>No Select</li>
</ul>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
/******************************************************
* CSS Reset
* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
* v2.0 | 20110126
******************************************************/
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}

body {
    line-height: 1;
}

ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}

blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
/*************************************************************
* End CSS Reset
*************************************************************/

ul.contentMenu li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;    
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;    
    color: #000;
    cursor: default;
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding:5px;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;
    border: 1px #ddd solid;
    border-bottom:0px;
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

ul.contentMenu li.pesudoClassHover  {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

ul.contentMenu ul {
    z-index: 10;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 22px;
    left: -1px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #aaa;
    border-top:1px solid #ddd;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;  
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;    
    background-color: #fff; /* Important fixes Ie.7. bug where relatively positioned element overlaps absolutely positioned element */
}

/* Keep this seperate and above first child declaration otherwise it breaks I.e. 8 */
ul.contentMenu ul li {
    border: none; /* Important - Reset border */
    border-radius: 0px; /* Important - Reset border */
    padding:5px;
    margin: 0px;
    float: none;
    text-align: left;
    text-shadow: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-left:1px solid #ddd;
    border-right:1px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
}

ul.contentMenu ul li a {
    display: block;
    border: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#000;
    padding:5px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

ul.contentMenu li ul li:hover { 
    background-color: #ddd;
}

ul.contentMenu ul li:last-child {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}

ul.contentMenu li ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}
```

**JavaScript (With Solution)**

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
        //Javascript for desktop navigation
        $('ul.jsGeneralNavigation > li').on('mouseenter', function() 
        {                   
            $(this).addClass('pesudoClassHover');
            $(this).children('ul').show();
        });   

        //Javascript for desktop navigation
        $('ul.jsGeneralNavigation > li').on('mouseleave', function(e) 
        {
            //This is the fix to prevent the select triggering the mouse leave
            if(e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() != "select") {
                $(this).removeClass('pesudoClassHover');
                $(this).children('ul').hide();
            }
        });   
});
```

Comment: Use `mouseenter` instead of `mouseover`. See http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/xrd2b42L/10/

Comment: I guess the problem is, that when hovering over the select you trigger the mouseleave event

Comment: @bwright is right (not intended). Removing the mouseleave event fixes the problem.

Comment: @kano is correct. The mouse leave event seems to be the problem.

Comment: The question was falsely marked as a duplicate. Since I can't provide a proper answer, I'll try to create a fiddle for you. The issue with the mouseleave event handler is the element to which you bind it. At the moment it is `ul.jsGeneralNavigation li` but it should handle all the subelements as well.

Comment: @Kano Thanks, I'll be interested in what you come up with. The handler was just meant to be a generic class so that I could attach it to any particular menu without worrying about its contents.

Comment: @Kano I've managed to fix, updated fiddle and code. Turns out the mouseleave event is triggered even if the select is a child of the parent element. Not too sure why as this shouldn't be the default behaviour.

Comment: Nice, glad you figured it out. The way I was going about it was checking for a [hover event](http://jsfiddle.net/xrd2b42L/22/) in the mouseleave, but your `target` approach of the event is much cleaner! (I couldn't find the right element for the hover event anyways)